# Flutter ToggleSwitch doesn’t change color

Tags: flutter, toggleswitch

I have a ToggleSwitch, it works fine with setState, but as long as I’m calling setState in its onToggle, it’s activeBgColor doesn’t change anymore. No matter which button is on toggle, the activeBgColor will always on the first choice, but the setState value is changing.

Plus I was trying to place it in the horizontal middle of the container, so I put it in a Row, but it still sticks at the beginning of the container

Here is the code:

```
 class _MyPovPageState extends State<MyPovPage> {
  final userUID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  final tm = TaskManager();
  final wmy = [Text('Week'), Text('Month'), Text('Year')];

  late final en;
  late final username;
  late final background;
  var myTask = [];
  var myDaily = [];
  var myHistory = [];
  var dailyTemp = [];
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initInfo();
  }

  initInfo() {
    database.child(userUID).onValue.listen((event) {
      final data = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as Map);
      setState(() {
        username = data['username'];
        background = data['background'];
        final language = data['language'];
        en = language.toString().startsWith('en');

        if (data['myDaily'] != null) {
          final dailyMap = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(data['myDaily']);
          dailyMap.forEach((key, value) {
            myDaily.add(tm.fromJson(value));
            //myTask.add(tm.fromJson(value));
          });
        }

        if (data['myTask'] != null) {
          final taskMap = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(data['myTask']);
          taskMap.forEach((key, value) {
            myTask.add(tm.fromJson(value));
          });
        }

        if (data['history'] != null) {
          final historyMap = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(data['history']);
          historyMap.forEach((key, value) {
            myHistory.add(tm.fromJson(value));
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(background),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )),
            child: ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 90),
              children: [
                getHello(),
                const SizedBox(height: 25),
                getDailyTaskWidget(),
                const SizedBox(height: 12),
                getChartWidget(),
                const SizedBox(height: 25),
                getTaskHeading(),
                getTaskList(),
              ],
            )));
  }

  Widget getChartWidget() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
      child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
          child: Column(children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(width: 14),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 14),
                    Text(en ? 'Score Chart' : '积分图表',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
                    const SizedBox(height: 4),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Text('-',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
                        Text(en ? 'Daily' : '日常任务',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
                        const SizedBox(width: 14),
                        const Text('-',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
                        Text(en ? ' Wishes' : ' 愿望分',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
                        const SizedBox(width: 14),
                        const Text('-',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
                        Text(en ? ' Surprises' : ' 惊喜分',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.none)),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 14),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                wmy[selectedIndex],
                const SizedBox(height: 14),
                const SizedBox(height: 14),
                getBigToggle(),
                const SizedBox(height: 14),
              ],
            )
          ])),
    );
  }

  Widget getBigToggle() {
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      ToggleSwitch(
        totalSwitches: 3,
        minWidth: 100.0,
        minHeight: 16.0,
        fontSize: 12,
        cornerRadius: 20.0,
        activeBgColor: [
          Color.fromARGB(255, 218, 203, 246),
        ],
        activeFgColor: Colors.black,
        inactiveBgColor: Colors.white,
        inactiveFgColor: Colors.black,
        labels: [en ? 'Week' : '周', en ? 'Month' : '月', en ? 'Year' : '年'],
        onToggle: (index) {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = index!;
          });
        },
      )
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide full widget?

Comment: Just edited and provided the full widget

Comment: Can you include more about `ToggleSwitch` and provide simplified version of snippet that will reproduce the same issue. You can try passing `selectedIndex` to those methods if it has scope issue it will resolve.

Comment: There is already issue open for this bug https://github.com/PramodJoshi/toggle_switch/issues/56 but you can workaround that by changing selectedIndex  type from var to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change selectedIndex type from var to int

```
  int selectedIndex = 0;
```

Or
You can specify **initialLabelIndex** property of ToggleSwitch and pass selectedIndex to it.

```
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  ToggleSwitch(
    initialLabelIndex: selectedIndex,
    totalSwitches: 3,
    minWidth: 100.0,
    minHeight: 16.0,
    fontSize: 12,
    cornerRadius: 20.0,
    activeBgColor: [
      Color.fromARGB(215, 118, 203, 146),
      Color.fromARGB(123, 218, 203, 246),

    ],

    labels: [en ? 'Week' : '周', en ? 'Month' : '月', en ? 'Year' : '年'],
    onToggle: (index) {
      setState(() {
        selectedIndex = index!;
      });
    },
  )
```

Comment: Changing selectedIndex to int doesn't help, but passing it to initialLabelIndex worked. Thank you!